# Getting a curl handle to use curl_easy_escape in libcurl

Tags: curl, libcurl

I'm trying to use the built in URL escape functionality in the libcurl library, [curl_easy_escape](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html). However, it requires a CURL* handle to work, and I would like to encapsulate the URL escape in a helper function. What is the best practice?

Can I call curl_easy_init every time I want to do a URL escape, like this

```
std::string url_encode(const char* msg)
{
    CURL* c = curl_easy_init();
    char* encoded = curl_easy_escape(c, msg, 0);
    std::string retval = encoded;
    curl_free(encoded);
    curl_easy_cleanup(c);
    return retval;
}
```

Does this approach have any drawbacks, if I make sure it's only called after curl_global_init?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: if you dont want the overhead of creating/deleting curl handles on each invocation, `static CURL* c = NULL; if(!c){c=curl_easy_init();~~}`

Comment: and you may want a length parameter. remember that url encoding supports binary data, strlen(char*) does not.